# conversions problem

Tags: marketing-cloud, lead-conversion, conversion, email-studio

We have installed the complete code in every page of our site, before closing the body tag, we have also installed the conversion code on our website, the code retrieves the information, but we do not get to A view on the conversions from Marketing Cloud, we are always at 0 conversions and 0 € of turnover

How can i activate conversions on Marketing cloud, And have the number of conversions made from emails sent from Marketing Cloud?

Comment: i have installed "the collect code" in every page in my website after the  </body> tag:   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://1*******.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "1*******"]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
</script>

Comment: And i install the conversion code too, in the confirmation page :  
_etmc.push(["trackConversion", {"cart" : [{
"item" : "INSERT_ITEM",
"quantity" : "INSERT_QUANTITY",
"price" : "INSERT_PRICE"
}],
 // OPTIONAL PARAMETERS
 "order_number" : "INSERT_ORDER_NUMBER",
"discount" : "INSERT_DISCOUNT",
"shipping" : "INSERT_SHIPPING"
 // END OPTIONAL PARAMETERS
 }
]);

Comment: Are you using conversion=“true” on your a href links in your email?